# List Cloud Service Classic use PowerShell and Azure Rest API

Tags: azure, rest, powershell, azure-rest-api

I Have a problem. Could you please help me view list Cloud Service Classic use PowerShell and Azure Rest API. When I used script for Web APP I show list Web APP, but when I used scrip for Cloud Service Classic I show error.

```bsh
# Variables
$TenantId = "" # Enter Tenant Id.
$ClientId = "" # Enter Client Id.
$ClientSecret = "" # Enter Client Secret.
$Resource = "https://management.core.windows.net/"
$SubscriptionId = "" # Enter Subscription Id.



$RequestAccessTokenUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/token"

$body = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$ClientId&client_secret=$ClientSecret&resource=$Resource"

$Token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $RequestAccessTokenUri -Body $body -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Write-Host "Print Token" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Output $Token

# Get Azure Resource Groups
$ResourceGroupApiUri = "https://management.core.windows.net/$SubscriptionId/services/hostedservices"

$Headers = @{}

$Headers.Add("Authorization","$($Token.token_type) "+ " " + "$($Token.access_token)")

$ResourceGroups = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $ResourceGroupApiUri -Headers $Headers

Write-Host "Print Resource groups" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Output $ResourceGroups
```

Invoke-RestMethod : ForbiddenErrorThe server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and 
is associated with this subscription.

Comment: This may not matter, but in your `$headers` entry, you have two spaces after your token type.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a built-in ASM PowerShell to list the cloud services associated with the current subscription.

```
Get-AzureService
```

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicemanagement/azure/get-azureservice?view=azuresmps-4.0.0

**Besides**, if you insist on calling the ASM rest api with powershell, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2015/06/02/azure-rest-api-powershell-retrieve-cloud-service-configuration/), the sample calls the [`Get Deployment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloudservices/rest-get-deployment) api, just change it to [`List Cloud Services`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloudservices/rest-list-cloud-services).

```
#Request Headers required to invoke the GET DEPLOYMENT REST API
$method
=
“GET”
$headerDate
= ‘2009-10-01’
$headers
= @{“x-ms-version”=“$headerDate“}

#Retrieving the subscription ID
$subID
= (Get-AzureSubscription
-Current).SubscriptionId 
$URI
=
https://management.core.windows.net/$subID/services/hostedservices/kaushalz/deployments/4f006bb7d2874dd4895f77a97b7938d0

#Retrieving the certificate from Local Store
$cert
= (Get-ChildItem
Cert:\CurrentUser\My
|
?{$_.Thumbprint -eq
“B4D460D985F1D07A6B9F8BFD67E36BC53A4490FC”}).GetRawCertData()

#converting the raw cert data to BASE64
body
=
“<Binary>—–BEGIN CERTIFICATE—–`n$([convert]::ToBase64String($cert))`n—–END CERTIFICATE—–</Binary>”

#Retrieving the certificate ThumbPrint
$mgmtCertThumb
= (Get-AzureSubscription
-Current).Certificate.Thumbprint

#Passing all the above parameters to Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet
Invoke-RestMethod
-Uri
$URI
-Method
$method
-Headers
$headers
-CertificateThumbprint
” B4D460D985F1D07A6B9F8BFD67E36BC53A4490FC”
-ContentType
$ContentType
```